# How to make several elements overlap using display flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-position, display

First, my code:

```
    <main class="main">
      <h1 class="title">A title here</h1>
      <h2>Another Element Here <span id="subtitle"></span></h2>
      <h3 id="thirdtitle">h3 el here</h3>
      <div class="overlay" id="one">An alert message here!</div>
      <div class="overlay" id="two">
        Another alert message here
      </div>
      <div class="overlay" id="three">A third alert message here, relaunch? <span id="startappagain">Click me </span></div>
      <div id="gridelement" class="grid"></div>
    </main>
```

1st question:

I'm using display flex, flex-direction column and justify-content: center and align-items: center on main, I made some interactions on gridelement using JS and "one", "two" and "three" are just alerts so their visibility is set on hidden, and sometimes, they become visible for 1 second when there's an error during the interaction with the JS in the gridelement element.

But when using visibility, unlike display: none, they still take up normal space so there's blank space between h3 and gridelement most of the time, so I would like to have the three elements overlap to minimize the blank space. I've tried playing around with positions which is tricky with display flex. Any idea for something clean? Thanks!

Additional question:

I was also thinking of having the messages just overlap the grid, but since I'm using flex on the grid elements as well, it would just mess up the whole design of the gridelement elements if I had them in the grid (especially that there's nothing in gridelement initially, everything is created in my JS), any idea how I could just make the messages appear in the middle of the screen? They stay there for a second anyway.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to use `max-height` property along with `visibility` like this:

```
.overlay {
  max-height: 1000px;
}

.overlay.hidden {
  max-height: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I hadn't thought of that strategy. Your answer will probably help many other people in the future!

Comment: Happy to help you